# Finding the optimal combination of inputs which return maximal output for a black box model

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, regression, supervised-learning

One of the challenges that I have been facing when applying ANN to regression tasks on my job is that in order to find the optimal out for a given range of inputs, I have to feed a multidimensional meshgrid to my model and then simply pick the highest value. However, this is overall a very computationally costly solution. The lenght of the text bellow might be scary but it just my attempt to better explain it.

Let me explain with other words. Supposing that I have 9 inputs for my ANN, and then I want to check which combinations of values of my features that returns me the highest outcome. I am currently overcoming the problem by just creating a 9D-mesh and simply predict the value for each sample and then identifying the optimal row. Nevertheless, this takes an exhaustive amount of time to work. Therefore, I am looking for a way be able to more efficiently reach this optimal output value, if possible at all.

In code, it would look something like this: (just a simple and made up example not really realistic in python):

```
import numpy as np
from itertools import product
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split 
import tensorflow.keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
import pandas as pd
import math

x1 = np.linspace(0,20,6)
x2 = np.linspace(0,20,6)
X = pd.DataFrame((product(*[x1,x2])))
y1 = 5*np.cos(np.deg2rad(X[0]))
y2 = 5 - 1*np.exp((-X[0]**2/np.deg2rad(10)**2)*np.cos(np.deg2rad(X[1])))
y = np.array([y1 + y2]).T
```

Setting a blackbox model, in this case, a neural network

```
x_scaler = MinMaxScaler()
y_scaler = MinMaxScaler()
X_scaled = x_scaler.fit_transform(X)
y_scaled = y_scaler.fit_transform(y)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X_scaled, y_scaled, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(100, input_dim = 2, activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dense(100, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(100, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation = 'relu'))
model.compile(optimizer = 'Adam', loss = 'mean_squared_error')
epochs_hist = model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs = 100, batch_size = 50, validation_split = 0.2)
```

Now that I fit my model, I will use the meshgrid for several intervals in order to find the optimal in the specified range:

```
x1_pred = np.linspace(0,20,21) 
x2_pred = np.linspace(0,20,21)
X_pred = pd.DataFrame((product(*[x1_pred,x2_pred])))
X_pred_test = x_scaler.fit_transform(X_pred)
y_pred = model.predict(X_pred_test)
y_pred = y_scaler.inverse_transform(y_pred)
```

So, supposing that I doing something similar for reaching the optimal, but in this case with 9 inputs, then it is clear how computionally unfeasiable that calculation will be. Hence, it comes my question of how to find the optimal combination of inputs which return maximal output of a blackbox model such as ANN.

Comment: Would genetic algorithm be something you would consider? I don’t know how expensive it is to evaluate a possible combination of inputs.

Comment: I'm not sure I've understood what you're trying to do, but if you're trying to find minima/maxima you should have a look at `scipy.optimize` which has several algorhytms implemented that could help you

Comment: @MayowaAyodele It is one possibility. However, I am not sure how I would use it in that situation.

Comment: @Nathan Unfortunately it won't be possible to use scipy.optimize as we are working with a blackbox model. Hence, there is no explicity equation to optimize and find minimum and maximum.

Comment: Couldn't you wrap the model into a function and pass that to scipy?

Comment: Effectively, you have 9 inputs, and a function `model.predict()` that need to be optimized, you could pass that to scipy.optimize.minimize() right?

Comment: @Nathan no. Perhaps I could in that example where I have a function. However that function over there was just to generate data in case someone wants to try any code. In my real scenario, I would use strictly data and would apply a ML algorithm to my model. In that case, I am using a ANN

Comment: Right, and then you want to find the maximum output that model can generate no?

Comment: @Nathan Yes. And more importantly, which inputs will return me the maximum output.

Comment: Let me write this out as an answer, maybe it makes more sense then

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an example of how you could get the 'best result' from a model. The important parts are `optimize`, `_get_simplex` and `_call_model`. By doing it this way you reduce the amount of calls necessary to your model.

```
from sklearn.ensemble import GradientBoostingRegressor
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize
from copy import copy


class Example:

    def __init__(self):
        self.X = np.random.random((10000, 9))
        self.y = self.get_y()
        self.clf = GradientBoostingRegressor()
        self.fit()

    def get_y(self):
        # sum of squares, is minimum at x = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ... ]
        return np.array([[self._func(i)] for i in self.X])

    def _func(self, i):
        return sum(i * i)

    def fit(self):
        self.clf.fit(self.X, self.y)

    def optimize(self):
        x0 = [0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5]
        initial_simplex = self._get_simplex(x0, 0.1)
        result = minimize(fun=self._call_model,
                          x0=np.array(x0),
                          method='Nelder-Mead',
                          options={'xatol': 0.1,
                                   'initial_simplex': np.array(initial_simplex)})
        return result

    def _get_simplex(self, x0, step):
        simplex = []
        for i in range(len(x0)):
            point = copy(x0)
            point[i] -= step
            simplex.append(point)

        point2 = copy(x0)
        point2[-1] += step
        simplex.append(point2)
        return simplex

    def _call_model(self, x):
        prediction = self.clf.predict([x])
        return prediction[0]

example = Example()
result = example.optimize()
print(result)
```

Of course, if you want to maximize instead of minimize, you can return `-prediction[0]` instead of `prediction[0]` to trick scipy.

Comment: Interesting solution, however, how would that that optimize works for a case of a blackbox model such as the ANN? At least from my understanding so far, since you cannot find out an explicit function, would be impossible to apply an optimizer with minimize

Comment: You don't need an explicit function with nelder-mead, there are multiple approaches that optimize black box models. The one you need depends on your computational power, time, presence of local minima and how volatile the results are.

Comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html you can check out the list of available models that could be of interest

Comment: In this example the problem I'm optimizing is also a black box model. I have literally no clue what `GradientBoostingRegressor` does

Comment: @Nathan I have the same problem but with constraints. I tried SLSQP but it returns me values around the initial guess always. Probably needs gradient information which I cannot give. And Nelder-mead does not support constraints. What do you suggest ?

Comment: @SiddhantTandon I'm sure there's a nice solution, but I'd hack it in by hand. If you open a question and link it here it'll be easier to show.

Comment: @Nathan thanks for the response [here is the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65382539/product-feature-optimization-with-constraints)