# Product feature optimization with constraints

Tags: python-3.x, optimization, scipy-optimize, lightgbm

I have trained a Lightgbm model on learning to rank dataset. The model predicts relevance score of a sample. So higher the prediction the better it is. Now that the model has learned I would like to find the best values of some features that gives me the highest prediction score.

So, lets say I have features `u,v,w,x,y,z` and the features I would like to optimize over are `x,y,z`.

```
maximize f(u,v,w,x,y,z) w.r.t features x,y,z where f is a lightgbm model
subject to constraints : 
y = Ax + b
z = 4 if y < thresh_a else 4-0.5 if y >= thresh_b  else 4-0.3
thresh_m < x <= thresh_n
```

The numbers are randomly made up but constraints are linear.

Objective function with respect to `x` looks like the following :

[image]

So the function is very spiky, non-smooth. I also don't have the gradient information as `f` is a lightgbm model.

Using [Nathan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59576663/finding-the-optimal-combination-of-inputs-which-return-maximal-output-for-a-blac) I wrote down the following class :

```
class ProductOptimization:
    
    def __init__(self, estimator,  features_to_change, row_fixed_values, 
                 bnds=None):
        self.estimator = estimator 
        self.features_to_change = features_to_change
        self.row_fixed_values = row_fixed_values
        self.bounds = bnds
                    
    def get_sample(self, x):
        
        new_values = {k:v for k,v in zip(self.features_to_change, x)}
        
        return self.row_fixed_values.replace({k:{self.row_fixed_values[k].iloc[0]:v} 
                                  for k,v in new_values.items()})
    
    def _call_model(self, x):
        
        pred = self.estimator.predict(self.get_sample(x))
        return pred[0]
    
    def constraint1(self, vector):
        x = vector[0]
        y = vector[2]
        return # some float value
    
    def constraint2(self, vector):
        x = vector[0]
        y = vector[3] 
        return #some float value
    
    def optimize_slsqp(self, initial_values):
        
        con1 = {'type': 'eq', 'fun': self.constraint1}
        con2 = {'type': 'eq', 'fun': self.constraint2}
        cons = ([con1,con2])

        
        result = minimize(fun=self._call_model,
                          x0=np.array(initial_values),
                          method='SLSQP',
                          bounds=self.bounds,
                          constraints=cons)
        return result
```

The results that I get are always around the initial guess. And I think its because of non-smoothness of the function and absence of any gradient information which is important for the SLSQP optimizer. Any advices how should I deal with this kind of problem ?

Comment: [cs.se] might be a better place to ask. Also, your first image looks very messed up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been a good minute since I last wrote some serious code, so I appologize if it's not entirely clear what everything does, please feel free to ask for more explanations

The imports:

```
from sklearn.ensemble import GradientBoostingRegressor
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize
from copy import copy
```

First I define a new class that allows me to easily redefine values. This class has 5 inputs:

1. value: this is the 'base' value. In your equation `y=Ax + b` it's the `b` part
2. minimum: this is the minimum value this type will evaluate as
3. maximum: this is the maximum value this type will evaluate as
4. multipliers: the first tricky one. It's a list of other InputType objects. The first is the input type and the second the multiplier. In your example `y=Ax +b` you would have `[[x, A]]`, if the equation was `y=Ax + Bz + Cd` it would be `[[x, A], [z, B], [d, C]]`
5. relations: the most tricky one. It's also a list of other InputType objects, it has four items: the first is the input type, the second defines if it's an upper boundary you use `min`, if it's a lower boundary you use `max`. The third item in the list is the value of the boundary, and the fourth the output value connected to it

**Watch out** if you define your input values too strangely I'm sure there's weird behaviour.

```
class InputType:

    def __init__(self, value=0, minimum=-1e99, maximum=1e99, multipliers=[], relations=[]):
        """

        :param float value: base value
        :param float minimum: value can never be lower than x
        :param float maximum: value can never be higher than y
        :param multipliers: [[InputType, multiplier], [InputType, multiplier]]
        :param relations: [[InputType, min, threshold, output_value], [InputType, max, threshold, output_value]]
        """
        self.val = value
        self.min = minimum
        self.max = maximum
        self.multipliers = multipliers
        self.relations = relations

    def reset_val(self, value):
        self.val = value

    def evaluate(self):
        """
        - relations to other variables are done first if there are none then the rest is evaluated

        - at most self.max
        - at least self.min
        - self.val + i_x * w_x
        i_x is input i, w_x is multiplier (weight) of i
        """
        for term, min_max, value, output_value in self.relations:
            # check for each term if it falls outside of the expected terms
            if min_max(term.evaluate(), value) != term.evaluate():
                return self.return_value(output_value)

        output_value = self.val + sum([i[0].evaluate() * i[1] for i in self.multipliers])
        return self.return_value(output_value)

    def return_value(self, output_value):
        return min(self.max, max(self.min, output_value))
```

Using this, you can fix the input types sent from the optimizer, as shown in `_call_model`:

```
class Example:

    def __init__(self, lst_args):
        self.lst_args = lst_args

        self.X = np.random.random((10000, len(lst_args)))
        self.y = self.get_y()
        self.clf = GradientBoostingRegressor()
        self.fit()

    def get_y(self):
        # sum of squares, is minimum at x = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ... ]
        return np.array([[self._func(i)] for i in self.X])

    def _func(self, i):
        return sum(i * i)

    def fit(self):
        self.clf.fit(self.X, self.y)

    def optimize(self):
        x0 = [0.5 for i in self.lst_args]
        initial_simplex = self._get_simplex(x0, 0.1)
        result = minimize(fun=self._call_model,
                          x0=np.array(x0),
                          method='Nelder-Mead',
                          options={'xatol': 0.1,
                                   'initial_simplex': np.array(initial_simplex)})
        return result

    def _get_simplex(self, x0, step):
        simplex = []
        for i in range(len(x0)):
            point = copy(x0)
            point[i] -= step
            simplex.append(point)

        point2 = copy(x0)
        point2[-1] += step
        simplex.append(point2)
        return simplex

    def _call_model(self, x):
        print(x, type(x))
        for i, value in enumerate(x):
            self.lst_args[i].reset_val(value)

        input_x = np.array([i.evaluate() for i in self.lst_args])
        prediction = self.clf.predict([input_x])
        return prediction[0]
```

I can define your problem as shown below **(be sure to define the inputs in the same order as the final list, otherwise not all the values will get updated correctly in the optimizer!)**:

```
A = 5
b = 2
thresh_a = 5
thresh_b = 10
thresh_c = 10.1
thresh_m = 4
thresh_n = 6

u = InputType()
v = InputType()
w = InputType()
x = InputType(minimum=thresh_m, maximum=thresh_n)
y = InputType(value = b, multipliers=([[x, A]]))
z = InputType(relations=[[y, max, thresh_a, 4], [y, min, thresh_b, 3.5], [y, max, thresh_c, 3.7]])


example = Example([u, v, w, x, y, z])
```

Calling the results:

```
result = example.optimize()
for i, value in enumerate(result.x):
    example.lst_args[i].reset_val(value)
print(f"final values are at: {[i.evaluate() for i in example.lst_args]}: {result.fun)}")
```